# What is the best installer?

Tags: windows, installation

Poll: What is the best and easy to use installer to use with .NET 3.5 SP1 windows applications?

Comment: Overlaps or dupe with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers

Comment: It all depends on the size of your application, and the number of different environments you're going to install it to, and who is going to run those installers.

Answer (score 19):

#### My vote is for:

[**Nullsoft Scriptable Install System**](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) - it's popular, easy to use and FREE

> **Nullsoft Scriptable Install System**
>   (NSIS) is a script-driven Windows
>   installation system with minimal
>   overhead backed by Nullsoft, the
>   creators of Winamp. NSIS has risen to
>   popularity as a widely used
>   alternative to commercial and
>   proprietary products like
>   InstallShield. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System)

There is rich plugins directory for NSIS, where you can find for example a plugin for installing windows services.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category:Plugins

#### Commercial alternatives:

- [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) - probably the most popular one and the most expensive option
- [Wise](http://www.wise.com) - also very popular
- [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) - new and nice, not that popular yet, but trending

#### Other:

- [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) - could be very good if you can spent some time on the learning curve. It is used by many Microsoft products.
- [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

#### [List of Installation Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) at Wikipedia

Comment: Does it support installing of Windows Services?

Comment: Check it's plugins directory.

Comment: For the record: Symantec has stopped selling Wise.

Comment: For the record: Microsoft has stopped "Setup Project from Visual Studio"

Comment: For the record: Microsoft has re-introduced the setup project as an extension.

Answer (score 8):

My personal preference is [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), it has a nice GUI for creation and editing of projects which are XML files so fits into source control easily.

Answer (score 4):

[Innosetup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is the fastest one I've used to make setup files quickly and easily (out of Nullsoft and VS), providing you get the designer that is a [separate download](http://www.istool.org/).

Comment: InnoSetup is great for relatively simple installers.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've used both [InstallShield](http://www.acresso.com/products/is/installshield-overview.htm) and [Wise](http://www.symantec.com/business/wise-installation-studio). I wouldn't say that using either of them is a joy, but they get the job done for large Windows applications.

Of the two, I would generally favour InstallShield.

Answer (score 2):

I very much like [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which is said to be the installer used by MS internally for Office.

Comment: And Flight Simulator http://www.joyofsetup.com/category/flight-simulator/

Comment: WiX has been a disappointment. The Repair fails far too often on customers' machines, and I cannot reproduce the problem. The log files are uninformative, cryptic and useless. The XML format is byzantine. About the only good thing is it's text-based and free (and worth every penny). I'm looking for alternatives. You don't get what you don't pay for.

Answer (score 2):

I used [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) on my first-and-last Windows project, and was quite happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ClickOnce deployment, if your environment allows you to do so. (If it's convenient).

Actually any answer could apply to your question here, choosing the "right" installer never possible for "a windows application".

- How many different machines are your going to install to?
- How large is your application?
- Does it have many dependencies? (Databases etc.)
- What is the "level" of the users who are going to install your app? Are they system administrators who install apps for a living, or are they joe-random "Hey lets click install because it looks cool" types.

just my 2ct.

Comment: Avoid ClickOnce like the plague, just my two cents!

Answer (score 1):

The one out of the box from Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: It is good for small applications.

Answer (score 0):

Nullsoft Scriptable Install System anytime... simply because of it's ease of use and more than that, it's free!