# How to make installer C#, including FFmpeg instalation

Tags: installation

I've made a YouTube MP3 downloader and I'm using FFmpeg in my project.

How can I make an installer that includes the FFmpeg installation?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734057/what-is-the-best-installer

Comment: And https://superuser.com/questions/38221/install-software-choose-msi-or-exe

Comment: Since ffmpeg is just a bunch of files, they can be packaged with the rest of your application.