# Windows: Make installer from an executable file

Tags: python, windows, installation

I have built an application into a single executable file `myapp.exe`.  The application runs perfectly from the executable file, for example if you place it on the Desktop and double click it.  How can I create an installer file `setup.exe` that will install this in Windows?

A little more detail in case it helps: the application is written in `Python 3.6` and was built into a single `exe` file with `pyinstaller`.  I can also build the application into a single folder if there's any advantage to starting from there over a single exe file.

Comment: you can subclass the `win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework` if you want it to run in the Windows Services layer. More here: https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2018/08/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of installers that you can go with. Please check the [What is the best installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734057/what-is-the-best-installer) topic for details.

Most of the packaging tools have a freeware edition with basic features enabled, except the ones that are already free (Wix). Considering your scenario, there is no need for a commercial license.

InstallShield has the **LE edition**. Advanced Installer has the **freeware one**. Here's a [step by step tutorial](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html) to get your installer in Advanced Installer.

If using VS, then you can package directly your app from the IDE, as multiple packaging tools offer extension for VS:

- [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/)
- [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ai-ext-vs.html)
- [InstallShield](https://info.flexerasoftware.com/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio)